# .NET Core 7 and ASP.NET authorization (with identity)

Tags: c#, authorization, claims-based-identity, claims

I am trying to implement a specific security setup using the tables provided by .NET Identity.

We are talking about the tables:

- `Aspnet.Users`: one row per user
- `Aspnet.Roles`: one row per role
- `Aspnet.UserRole`: cross-reference between user and role
- `Aspnet.UserClaims`: list of claims assigned directly to a user
- `Aspnet.RoleClaims`: list of claims assigned to a role.

I have "rights" that are assigned to my users (either directly or via roles):

```
CAN_PURCHASE_STUFF
CAN_MANAGE_EMPLOYEE_PROFILE
CAN_MODIFY_PRODUCT
CAN_CREATE_PRODUCT
etc..
```

A user can receive rights either DIRECTLY or through ROLES.

`RoleA` (ProductManager) will have the rights:

```
CAN_PURCHASE_STUFF
CAN_MODIFY_PRODUCT
CAN_CREATE_PRODUCT
```

`RoleB` (System_admin) will have the rights:

```
CAN_CREATE_PRODUCT
CAN_MANAGE_USER
CAN_... (and so on)
```

Essentially, all possible rights.

In the system, I have "security axes": user, departments, geographic region. The rights must always be applied based on an AXIS (or ALL axes).

A user can have roles but must also be "assigned" to an axis.

- User001 has the 'ProductManager' role, applied to DEPARTMENT A.
- User001 has the 'ProductManager' role, applied to DEPARTMENT B.
- User002 has the RIGHT 'CAN_MANAGE_EMPLOYEE_PROFILE' for ALL departments.
- ... and so on.

I then have a concept of "effective rights". This "breaks down" the rights by privilege.

For instance:

- User001 CAN_PURCHASE_STUFF DEPARTMENT=A (via a role)
- User001 CAN_MODIFY_PRODUCT DEPARTMENT=A (via a role)
- User001 CAN_CREATE_PRODUCT DEPARTMENT=A (via a role)
- User001 CAN_PURCHASE_STUFF DEPARTMENT=B (directly)
- User002 CAN_MANAGE_EMPLOYEE_PROFILE DEPARTMENT=ALL
- User003 CAN_MODIFY_PRODUCT DEPARTMENT=C (directly assigned)

My challenge lies with `UserClaims`.

How should I store this?

Currently, the UserClaims table only offers 'TYPE' and 'VALUE'.

If I want to store the concept of "right assigned via a ROLE (and which one), as well as the type of right, and the AXIS of the right, I will lack columns in the `Aspnet.UserClaims` table!

At the moment, I've created a custom table like this:

```
UserID: ...the user id...
RoleID: the roleID if assigned via a role
PrivilegeCode: the privilege code if a privilege is assigned directly
DepartmentID: the department ID if we want to limit
CustomerID: the customer ID if we want to restrict user rights.
```

However, I feel I am not utilizing the ASP.NET security model adequately (in fact, I don't even use the UserClaims table).
I feels that storing a "claim-value" with all my data would not be efficient

```
ClaimType:PRIVILEGE
ClaimValue:CAN_PURCHASE_STUFF|ROLE=ProductManager|DEPARTEMENT=A
```

But then, my Angular will have some intense pain trying to filter on that

Any advice?

I tried a lot if different approach.

I tried storing everything in my `Aspnet.UserClaims`, but it is not "clean" nor manageable.

I ended up doing a custom table, but I really don't want to extend the base model if it is already made for my needs.